# Table column partially dependent on another column?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I want to have two type `:boolean` columns, let's say X and Y, where Y is partially dependent on X. When X is true, Y can be either true or false, but when X is false, Y must be false. Is this possible?

```
class AddPrivacyColumnsToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column("posts", "public", :boolean, :default => true)
    add_column("posts", "collectable", :boolean, :default => true)
  end
end
```

where `public` is X, and `collectable` is Y, i.e. only public posts can be collected. If a post is set to private (when `public` is false), then `collectable` should automatically be set to false.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. There are many ways to achieve this but I'm not sure what you are looking for. Do you have any code you've been working on?

Comment: @kcdragon Just updated the question with the code from the migration file

Comment: Are you asking how to do this?

Comment: @kcdragon Yes, that's what I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a before save call back to Post

```
before_save :set_collectable 

def set_collectable 
  if !public? 
    self.collectable = false 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Since you mentioned there are several ways of doing this, just out of curiosity... what are some other ways of doing it?

Comment: You could add a database trigger but these aren't used too often in Rails. You could also use listeners like wisper or observer to set collectable instead of directly using callbacks. But I think what is in the answer is your best bet